# Deriving the homogeneous scaling of scattering amplitudes

Tags: quantum-field-theory, s-matrix-theory

I would like to derive the homogeneous scaling of scattering amplitudes $M(t\lambda,t^{-1}\tilde{\lambda})=t^{-2h}M(\lambda,\tilde{\lambda})$ in the following very general and first principled manner, however I seem to be missing one key step.

The fundamental requirement of the Lorentz covariance of the S-matrix for massless particles is stated as (Weinberg Vol 1 Eq (3.3.1), and neglecting the energy factors which are not important for the following argument)

\begin{equation}
M(\{p\})=e^{i\sum_{i=1}^nh_i\theta_i^W}M(\{\Lambda p\})\qquad (1)
\end{equation}
where $\{p\}$ denotes the set of particle momenta, $h_i$ their helicities, and $\theta_i^W$ their associated Wigner angles. Weinberg Vol I then realizes that one should write the amplitude as a function of the bispinors $\lambda^{l}(p)$
\begin{equation}
M(\{\lambda^l(p)\})=e^{i\sum_{i=1}^nh_i\theta_i^W}M(\{\lambda^l(\Lambda p)\})\qquad (2)
\end{equation}
where one chooses the bi-spinors $\lambda^l(p)$ such that they reproduce the Wigner phase when acted on by a finite dimensional representation $D_{l\bar{l}}(\Lambda)$  of the Lorentz group (5.96 of Weinberg):
\begin{equation}
\lambda_l(\Lambda p) e^{i h \theta_W(p,\Lambda)}=D_{l\bar{l}}(\Lambda)\lambda^{\bar{l}}(p)\qquad (3)
\end{equation}
Here $D_{l\bar{l}}(\Lambda)$ is a finite dimensional representation of the Lorentz group, for example the $(\frac{1}{2},0)$ representation etc.

Let us consider Eq (2) with a single particle and choose our Lorentz transformation to be a rotation about the $\hat{p}$ axis by an amount $\psi$, i.e. $\Lambda=R_p(\psi)$. It is a non-trivial fact that for rotations about a particles momentum axis the Wigner angle is the angle of rotation $\theta^W=\psi$. Eq (2) gives us
\begin{align}
M(\lambda^l(p))&=e^{ih\psi}M\bigg(\lambda^l\big(R_p(\psi)p\big)\bigg)\\
&=e^{ih\psi}M(\lambda^l(p))\qquad (4)
\end{align}

Eq.(4) seems to be contradiction (as $M(x)=tM(x)$ implying $M(x)=0$) instead of the statement of homogeneous scaling I was hoping for. Any clarification on how to derive homogeneous scaling in this manner would be greatly appreciated.